# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions Version=3.1.14.0 even I only use Version 2.1.1

Tags: dependency-injection

[image]
I'm getting this error even I only use Version 2.1.1

I tried removing the bin folder and re deploy again.

I checked for 3.1.14 version of it but I'm not sure if it will work since I didn't add that version.

Comment: You are missing binding redirects.